Win 7 drive from legacy Asus/AMD phenom 4 supported by HP Z-420 I7 as plug & play?
Need to know if HP Z-420 I7 will plug and play WIN 7 ultimate drive from legacy AMD Phenom II 4x system.  My old machine no post.  Fortunately have tested  bootable back up drive with all software.  I learned MBR v GPT the hard way as I have nice new Strix Ryzen 7 system that won't run legacy software.  Is DDR3 the limiter? I would like to buy the newest CPU/motherboard set which runs Win 7 ultimate drive from previous Asus/AMD combo. The legacy drive has Adobe Master 6 and a host of software that is now SaaS costing hundreds per month which I cannot afford.  Looking for youngest possible solution.  Thanks

https://superuser.com/a/1850373/653259

"Is DDR3 the limiter?" - The fact your system only supports DDR3 absolutely is not limiter. Windows 7 does not support the newest CPUs. Windows 7 does not boot on any system that support the current generation from both Intel and AMD.  Windows 7 is unsafe to use in 2024.

Security is not the issue.  My question is whether legacy drive from Asus/AMD Phenom II 4 core plug & play HP 420Z I7 9700?  If not what is the latest generation CPU/motherboard combo that will?   I need to know which is the  latest/newest generation that will plug & play bootable Win7 legacy drive.  Thanks

Are you asking us to recommend hardware? That is off topic. Or are you asking our help getting this old software to run on a specific HP computer model? That is probably on topic, but it is likely going to be difficult as it is HIGHLY unlikely the software will know how to talk to the hardware, and vice versa. Please focus your post on a single question, and provide more details.

Unfortunately, no Windows Operating System is portable. By that, I mean that you can't take a drive with a Windows installation on it, and just move it from one computer to another, unless the two computers have the exact same hardware. The reason being that the drivers Windows is using will expect a certain CPU, motherboard, GPU, and other components, it won't know how to operate different hardware.
What is even more unfortunate here, is that it's unlikely you will find that specific laptop, considering it came bundled with Windows 7. Maybe you can find the same one on a second hand shop online, but I am doubtful.
What I recommend is that you take the hard drive, and copy the data from it using a dock to another computer.  I can only imagine that the hard drive is possibly close to failing at this point, and Windows 7 has been unsupported for a few years now. The machine you migrate to is entirely your choice; you can go to another Windows Operating System (10 has one year left of free support), any Linux distro, a Mac computer, or Unix even.
I wish you luck.

The drive is from a off premise clone.  Old but unused.

What do you mean off-premise? Do you not own/possess the laptop and hard drive?

IF WIN7 install on I7 9700 will legacy MBR with boot track allow access to legacy software?

The clone drive has never been run except to test it (stored off premise).  Do I understand the bios chip from the legacy motherboard is the the limiting factor for plug&play?  The legacy drive is SataIII MBR and it bootable WIN7.  What is the newest generation CPU/motherboard combo that would read the drive?  Is it possible to install WIN7 on I7 9700 drive 1 and read legacy drive so i can access software? Legacy drive has boot track on it.  I checked and the legacy motherboard is available if I must go that route.

I'm seriously confused. Do you own the drive in question? Do you have it on you?

As I stated in my answer, the only way you are going to get that drive to boot is in the exact same hardware it was configured for. Any other configuration, and best case you can boot into safe mode with limited capabilities. Otherwise, you will just get a blue screen.

yes. i own and possess the drive.

My concern is to build a system that will allow me to access software on legacy MBR drive that has a boot track.  I would prefer not to invest in 12 year old technology.  I do not understand which versions of windows will support legacy software designed to run under Win7.  If I bought say I7 9700 with Win10 drive 1 MBR and "dock" legacy drive 2 MBR that has a boot track would I be able to access drive 2 legacy software and would it run under win10?  Thanks

BTW - legacy system is ATX desktop It is not possible to reinstall all legacy software due to change in market approach to SaaS vs legacy which was purchased.  Some of my software is 20 years old still valid and I dont want to waste time arguing with uncooperative vendors.

I'm sorry, but I don't know how to make this clearer. No, your Windows drive will only work with the exact same hardware it was configured for . That's it. You aren't magically going to put your 12 year old drive into a much newer system, and it will understand how to use that hardware. It has drivers for the AMD phenom 4, not for any Intel chipset. I'm sorry, but you don't have access to those programs anymore unless you can manage to find another laptop exactly like the one you took the drive out of.

@CaturdaySaint: Are you saying the hardware can never be changed once Windows is installed? For example, would upgrading a computer's video cause the computer not to boot? Wasn't Plug and Play introduced to allow at least some hardware to be changed?

Thank you.  Your answer is crystal clear and I have bought a new unused 12 year old motherboard to reestablish my software.

@DavidAnderson IF you uninstall the drivers for the old hardware, swap it out for the new devices, then install the drivers for the new hardware, you can change it. The situation Fish is in wasn't the case; they cloned a drive from another computer that no longer functions/they don't have access to, and want to install it into wildly different hardware and expect it to boot. Plug and play is for simple devices and peripherals; USB drives, video game controllers, stuff like that, not CPUs or the like.

@CaturdaySaint: I would question if your previous comment is completely true. I performed an experiment where I install Windows 7 in VMware Fusion Player virtual machine. I then made an exact copy of the virtual drive and transferred the copy to a completely different computer, where used the drive to build a VirtualBox virtual machine. The new virtual machine booted and detected different hardware and produced the "Driver Software Installation" window shown in this image.

You're comparing virtual machines, which can have their hardware tweaked on the fly, to physical machines that freak out if you install the wrong driver within the same family of hardware. It's not comparable.

I want to thank folks for their input.  I am sure this is a common problem.  Legacy system drive has thousands of dollars of legacy software that I use because I am familiar with it and given new SaaS monthly recurring charges it would cost me several hundred dollars a month to recreate the environment with little benefit from the newest versions.  I was able to buy new 12 year old parts so the simple solution is to recreate the 12 year old machine.  I spent $70 for the board and $150 for HAF full tower with new PS hoping CPU RAM etc still usable.  Adobe is run by scammers screwing taxpayers.
